# How to run GUI via remort server

Tags: qt, centos, segmentation-fault, glibc, xserver

I'm using Qtcreator to make GUI.

Ideally, I build the project in my local pc (CentOS virtual terminal),
and move it to remort server(CentOS).
Finally, I want to run it in windows system via X server(VcXsrv i use).

As operation verification, I create a new file and build as it is.
At first, it generates many errors in remort server, such as "**./test: /lib64/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.14 not found (required by /users/my/Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5)**".
I don't have root permission and can't update /lib64/, so download latest lib64 to my directory, and add to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
Previous error is solved but the error message "**segmentation fault (core dumped)**" comes to appear.

Why this problem occur even though it is a raw project?

Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple glibc libraries on a single host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so download latest lib64 to my directory, and add to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Previous error is solved but the error message "segmentation fault (core dumped)" comes to appear.

That will never work. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) explains what you should do instead.

Comment: Thanks. I try re-compile by referring to provided answer.