# Compiling: undefined reference "clock_gettime and memcpy" for Qt project

Tags: qt, centos, linker-errors, glibc, undefined-reference

I try to compile Qt project with CentOS.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257907/how-to-run-gui-via-remort-server) question describe what I have done in detail and 
I want to do with another glibc libraries **/users/my/lib64/** (I can't update /lib64/) by referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host/851229#851229).

This is the compile out put:

```
g++ ./main.o ./moc_widget.o ./widget.o \
  -o ./test -Wl,--rpath=/users/my/lib64 \
  -Wl,--rpath=/users/my/Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib \
  -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/users/my/lib64/libc.so.6 \
  -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/users/my/lib64/libz.so.1 \
  -L/users/my/Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Widgets \
  -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread  -lglib-2.0 -lrt -lX11 \
  -I/users/my/test/2 \
  -I/users/my/Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/include \
  -I/users/my/Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets \
  -I/users/my/Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore \
  -I/users/my/Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/include/QtGui
```

.pro file :

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = test
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

CONFIG += qt

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        widget.cpp 

HEADERS += \
        widget.h 

FORMS += \
        widget.ui
```

gcc version : 6.1.0

But the error:

```
    /users/my/Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `clock_gettime@GLIBC_2.17'
    /users/my/Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so: undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'
    collect2 ld returned exit 1 status
```

How to solve it ?

Comment: add your `.pro` file to question , seems a link error and include your gcc version

Comment: I'm confuse do you want to compile your project in local machine and deploy it to target machine or you want to compile project in target machie

Comment: Thanks. I modify my question.  Sorry for confusing, the former is ideal, but I can't run the application in target machine, so I try the latter.

Comment: Create a simple project and build. I want to check that you can build just a simple application or not?

Comment: I made simple project, only close button, but I use Qtcreator and pick up the release project, so I don't know too much about building with cui.

Comment: could you build that sucessfully

Comment: yes, I could run it in my local PC

Comment: is there a bin folder in /users/my/Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/

Comment: do you want to build you project in local pc

Comment: /users/my/Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/bin exists

Comment: Ideally, I want to build the project in my local PC and deploy it, but this project shows the error such as "GLIBC_2.12" in target PC.

Comment: I think during build process linker could not find ***.so** files in bin folder of your path you should add it to path in linux there is a method to add path in ubuntu check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path) and add path

Comment: I apoIogize taking your time. I add /users/my/Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/bin to PATH, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Use echo path to see and ensure you have added it ti path correctly and also run sudo ldconfig in terminal and try again

Comment: I want you to make sure that you have added path perfectly

Comment: I don't have root permission, so I can't run sudo ldconfig. Maybe root user don't add me to sudoers. I try asking him.

Answer (score 0):

```
g++ ./main.o ./moc_widget.o ./widget.o \
 -o ./test -Wl,--rpath=/users/my/lib64 \
 -Wl,--rpath=/users/my/Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib \
 -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/users/my/lib64/libc.so.6 \
 -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/users/my/lib64/libz.so.1 \
 -L/users/my/Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Widgets \
 -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread  -lglib-2.0 -lrt -lX11 \
 -I...
```

This command line is completely bogus (you didn't understand [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617)): there can only be *one* dynamic linker, and it should be `/users/my/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, and not `libz.so.1`. By using multiple `--dynamic-linker=...` flags, you are simply *replacing* previous (incorrect) setting with a new (also incorrect) one.

It's also bogus because specifying `-I...` flags on the *link* line without any sources is pointless.

If this command succeeded, you'd end up with an executable that would simply crash immediately, because `libz.so.1` is *not* a dynamic linker.

Now, your link fails because you are performing the link on the *wrong* system. You need to link on the *original* system (the one where you successfully linked your binary earlier, and the one which has GLIBC 2.17 or later). And then move the linked executable to your target system.

On the original system, your link command should look something like this:

```
g++ main.o moc_widget.o widget.o -o test \
   -Wl,-rpath=/users/my/lib64 \
   -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/users/my/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 \
 -L...
```

The two lines I indented above should be the *only* change from your original successful link command.